# Should a husband get the consent of his current wife(s) if he wishes to marry another woman?

Tags: nikah, wife, polygamy

Is it mandatory for a husband get the consent of his current wife(s) if he wishes to marry another woman?  And why?

If so, should he get the consent of all his wives in case he has more than one?

And if it's mandatory and he doesn't get the consent, knowingly or unknowingly, or the wife/wives refuse to give the consent, but still marries another woman, would the marriage be valid?

Comment: Related: [Can a wife deny her husband to marry more women?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/70229/20218)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to take the wife's consent for new marriage As it is the right for a man to have 4 wives due to Qur'an.

This Fatwa has another aspect, which the second or several marriage is under the country laws. For example, In Iran if you marry another woman without your wife's consent, your first wife can go to the court and take her divorce from her husband (without his allowance and either his consent) and also takes the half of the wealth of her husband.

Comment: Relevant source?

Comment: "In Iran ...", really? Of course not! In Iran rules are those of Islam and no one can modify such rules unless in the form of a temporary rule for the sake of some requirements. What you are trying to say is that the couple can suggest and accept or refuse some RATIONAL conditions to each other during their marriage. What you said is never a rule, the man can refuse to accept them at the marriage and the woman should decide if she still want to marry with him. Please modify your answer, it is not a country law.

Answer (score -1):

If a man wants a good marriage, then it is only logical to consult his wife/wives on such matters. If a man does not want a good marriage, then let the man drown in his own arrogance.

With the above being said, in Islam, a husband does not need permission of his wife/wives for marriage, this is a man's right as dictated in the Quran. This right comes with hefty responsibilities though, hence treat them all equally. That means if you buy one a car, then you buy all of them a car. This is not negotiable. This also includes love, there aren't many men out there who would be able to maintain that perfect balance.

Today I have seen many cases where a man has one wife in Europe, one in America, and one in Asia. The man stays with one in America, and completely neglects the rest. This is wrong as it breaks the condition which allows men to have more than one wife to begin with.

The source: **Surah Nisa, chapter 4 verse 3**

Comment: "If a man wants a good marriage, then it is only logical to consult his wife/wives on such matters. If a man does not want a good marriage, then let the man drown in his own arrogance" ... according to what??

Comment: @kmonsoor according to the fact that "consulting your wife" is not a sin, and not consulting your wife in such a huge decision is retarded in every aspect imaginable. You don't have to be Einstein to know how it could ruin a marriage. To top it all off, the prophet consulted his wives on matters, for example the case of umm salamah, and he accepted her consultation (which makes it a Sunnah). There are cases in the Quran also, cases depicting men accepting consultation from women of the household. These are sources of wisdom, and must be considered. Source: 28:9 - 28:26

Answer (score -2):

I present here a translated issue (based on Iran [an Islamic-Shia country]):

> In the third verse of Surah Al-Nisa ', God Almighty, although He has
> allowed men to marry up to four wives in a permanent marriage, but
> continues: "But if you are afraid of not doing justice, be content
> with only one wife."
>
> According to the Tasnim news agency media group, God Almighty in the
> third verse of Surah Nisa, although he has allowed men to marry up to
> four wives with permanent marriage, but continues: "But if you are
> afraid, do not observe justice only to one "Be content with your
> wife." This divine commandment has also been mentioned in the
> religious and legal texts of Islam, and although polygamy is allowed,
> conditions have been set for it.
>
> Prior to the enactment of the Family Protection Law in 1346 (solar year), there was
> no prohibition on polygamy for men, but for the first time in Article
> 14 of this law, remarriage of men was subject to the court's
> permission, and the court must investigate the current woman And the
> realization of justice between the spouses by him could have allowed
> the man to remarry; Of course, marriage without a court order could
> also lead to punishment for the man. These regulations continued with
> the enactment of the Family Protection Law approved in 1974, and in
> Article 16 of this law, the remarriage of men was made conditional on
> the conditions that will be mentioned below. The important point was
> that after the victory of the Islamic Revolution, although the bill to
> establish special civil courts was approved on October 1, 1979,
> emphasizing the implementation of sharia rules regarding marriage and
> divorce, but never the Family Protection Law approved in 1974. In the
> bill of 1958 and not in the subsequent views of the Guardian Council,
> it was not declared illegal and its validity remained. However, in the
> revision of the Family Protection Act in 1991, some sought to remove
> the condition of consent of the first spouse and court permission to
> make the path to remarriage smoother; Of course, this time, when in
> Article 23 of the proposed bill, the members of parliament considered
> the condition of court permission, the Guardian Council opposed it and
> considered it illegal. The exchanges of the family protection bill
> between the parliament and the Guardian Council eventually led to the
> deletion of the controversial Article 23 in this law, so that the same
> law of 1353 regarding the second marriage would survive. But how can
> men remarry?
>
> The conditions of the second marriage in the current laws Although in
> Islamic jurisprudence there is no restriction for men other than the
> condition of justice for remarriage up to four wives, but in 1353 and
> with the approval of Article 16 of the Family Protection Law, this
> issue was completely changed so that the law, the principle of
> prohibition of remarriage Men have stated that "a man can not have a
> second wife by having a wife, except in the following cases: 1- The
> consent of the first wife. 2 - Lack of power of the first spouse to
> perform marital duties. 3 - Disobedience of the wife to the husband.
> 4- A woman suffers from insanity or incurable diseases. 5- Sentencing
> a woman to imprisonment for more than six months. 6- Infection of a
> woman with any harmful addiction. 7 - Leaving family life on the part
> of the woman. 8 - Female infertility. 9 - The disappearance of a
> woman's disappearance » In the second to ninth paragraphs of this
> article, issues are raised that make a man's remarriage seem normal,
> but if the wife has no problems, is not sick, is not imprisoned and
> insane, and has a child, then the only way is To remarry, a man must
> obtain the consent of his first wife and obtain permission from the
> court. Of course, the fulfillment of the second to ninth clauses is
> with the court, and if the court does not fulfill it, it will not
> allow the man to remarry.
>
> Secret marriage is forbidden! A man who wants to remarry must file a
> lawsuit against his first wife to renew his marriage, in which he must
> state the reasons for his request to the court. The court also sends a
> copy of the petition to the first spouse at the appointed time to
> respond to it or prepare for the court hearing, after which the court
> takes the necessary measures and investigates the first wife and after
> attaining financial ability. The husband and the administration of
> justice between the spouses allow the husband to remarry, and if the
> husband does not have favorable financial conditions and the wife is
> willing to fulfill the marital duties, he will oppose her request.
> According to Article 56 of the Family Protection Act, marriage
> registrars do not have the right to register a remarriage without the
> permission of the court. "If he registers a marriage, he will be
> sentenced to Islamic deprivation and punishment for being a notary
> public." Because the official registration of a man's remarriage
> requires a court order, many men prefer to marry their second wife in
> secret, out of sight of their first wife.  In fact, without the
> official registration of a marriage, men only issue the legal form of
> a permanent marriage in order to be safe from the consequences of its
> official registration. However, according to Article 49 of the Family
> Protection Law, registration of a marriage is mandatory, and if a man
> enters into a permanent marriage without registration in the official
> offices, he will be sentenced to a fine of 80 to 180 million rials or
> imprisonment of 91 days to six months. But there are many men who
> either do not register their marriage or enter into a temporary
> marriage so that they no longer have to register it officially.

Reference: https://www.tasnimnews.com/fa/news/1396/03/03/1418308

Answer (score -3):

It is allowed to have more than 1 wife but your wife has to agreed, if she allowed it, then you can. But if she doesn't, you can't.

“Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allah have mercy on him) was asked about a man who married a woman, and she stipulated that he should not take another wife or make her move from her home, and that she could live with her mother, and he went ahead (with the marriage) on that basis. Is he obliged to adhere to that, and if he goes against these conditions, does the wife have the right to annul the marriage or not? "

```
          -source: Islamaqa.info
```

Comment: This answer needs some elaboration to be helpful. The quote is based on a condition made by the 1st wife. While in OP's question there's no quote about any condition, so the case is different.